# Recreating a 17th century book

Tags: typography

For whatever reason, I decided to undertake a hobby project of recreating (the first page of) Sir Thomas Browne's 16th century *Urne Burial* in TeX and friends.

[image]

I was inspired by [this effort](https://github.com/raphink/geneve_1564). So the questions I have are -

- How does one go about replicating the dropped capitals? I can only think of stripping them from a high resolution scan of the original page.
- Preliminary inspection of the letters makes me think this a variant of the Garamond typefaces. Is this correct? The italicized *Urne-Buriall* in the second line does not look like Garamond but...

Comment: Welcome to SE.X! Have you looked at the [Fell types](http://iginomarini.com/fell/the-revival-fonts/)?

Comment: You might try to reproduce  with `ebgaramond`,  which has a dedicated package, is an open type family of fonts and comprises an initial font, and has the `long s` feature.

Comment: The main question is: How accurate shall the reproduction in LaTeX be? Are you willing to include svg-images? In most cases there is a package doing the stuff, but sometimes there isn't. It is not unlikely that you might write your own. That's how I started my Lieder-package.

Comment: I'm taking a conservative approach - build from scratch whatever I can, and adopt the easy way out if the going gets tough. I'm willing to consider svg-images in such a scenario.

Comment: What I am curious about is tracing the exact font being used in the book. How does one check or even begin to research these things? @Bernard i did look at `ebgaramond` before, but I don't know if the italicized *Urne-Buriall* in the title is available as part of that package. Do you know if it is?

Comment: You start with some history and then make an educated guess. In 17th-century England, the types were mostly imported from Holland in the earlier part of the century, until Bishop Fell commissioned his own (the Fell types). To my eye, the "U" looks like something from a van Dyck font. The "English" font in the [Fell fonts recreation](http://iginomarini.com/fell/the-revival-fonts/) looks close, but the B is quite different.

Comment: If you can get a photo with a higher resolution, try submitting it to https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/  It’s best at identifying fonts which are for sale, but some designers hang out in the WhatTheFont forum and take an interest in historical typefaces.  (See, for instance, the story of Ronaldson Old Style at http://canadatype.net/fonts/ronaldson).

Comment: See https://archive.org/details/hydriotaphiaurne00browrich/page/n6  This attempted reproduction was printed by Houghton, Mifflin in Brimmer type, with ornaments by M. Lamont Brown.  See also the replica by Payson & Clarke at https://archive.org/details/hydriotaphiaurne00browuoft/page/n10 with its recommendation of Keynes’ _Bibliography of Sir Thomas Browne_.